# Inverses of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

> Let $G = \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a & a \\a & a \end{bmatrix} \mid a\in \mathbb{R},a \neq 0 \end{Bmatrix}.$
>
> Show that $G$ is a group under matrix multiplication.
>
> Explain why each element of $G$ has an inverse even though the matrices have determinant $0$.

I've managed to show that closure, associativity and identity indeed holds for this general linear group. The problem I'm facing is showing that inverses holds and what explanation can be provided for the existence of the inverse.

Only **hint** to be provided

Comment: Note the edit to the entries of the matrix

Comment: I cannot see any way how this set forms a group under standard matrix multiplication. What is the neutral element? The identity matrix is not in the set. Should it be a different group operation? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, re-read my statement. $I_2$ is not in $G$. The definition of  group I am familiar with demands the identity to be an element of that group.

Comment: I was under the assumption that $I_{2}$ is in G by definition of what Group meant. But the condition set on the set G requires a=/= 0. So this is another quandary.

Comment: There could exist another "identity" in the group though. One that doesn't really look like $I_2$ but still meets the definition of $Me = eM = M$.

Comment: Nephente: $G$ is not a subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$, so there is no need for the usual identity matrix to be in $G$.

Comment: @wj32 True. I was somehow convinced - without checking - that the id. matrix were the only neutral element wrt. matrix multiplication even on this particular subset of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the identity, so try solving for the inverse directly:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b&b\\b&b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}2ab&2ab\\2ab&2ab\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$

Do you see where to go from here? (remember we are solving for $b$ :))

I think that after you see the calculation of the inverse matrix, it will make more sense to you why the inverse is well-defined even though all the matrices have determinant zero.

Comment: We have $b=\frac{1}{4a}$ with $a=/=$ so b is well defined.

Comment: Does it make sense why it doesn't matter that the determinant is 0?

Comment: Yes. Any matrix, even if det=0, will have entries b=1/(4a) with a non-zero

Comment: That's true, but I think what is more important to note is that the identity in your group is not the `usual' identity for $2\times 2$ matrices, and the fact about invertibility and determinant only applies if we are aiming to get $I_2$, rather than the identity for this group $G$.

Comment: Maybe think about the isomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ by $\phi(\begin{bmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{bmatrix}) = a$ with a group operation $a*b = 2ab$. It's easy to see why this is (commutative) group, and the question about inverses and determinant doesn't come up because it's simply irrelevant to this group.

Comment: Good reference when I'm on the topic of Isomorphism.